# Unable to import page module using pyinstaller

Tags: exe, pyinstaller, py2exe

I am creating simple python to convert exe using pyinstaller.

python code (ch.py)

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "-E", "-c", "import page"],
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
print(p.returncode)
```

pyinstaller created ch.exe successfuly. But Getting error like unable to import page library when run exe, because pyinstaller does not consider page folder as library. After i tried to create exe with "paths=c:\mypro\page"

`pyinstaller --paths="c:\\mypro\\page" ch.py`

Again Getting same error

Thanks in advance

Comment: PyInstaller overwrite `sys.executable` in the built exe, so `sys.executable` no more points to python.exe.

Comment: thanks for response. After my research problem with "import page" because pyinstaller does not consider page folder as a library. then i tried like this "pyinstaller paths=c:\\mypro\\page ch.py" . but that is also throwing same error